# Android, push messages to 1000 devices fast

Tags: php, android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have implemented c2dm and it works fine that the device receives the message and everything.
There is however one problem that I can't find a solution for.

When a certain event occurs I want to push the same message to a few thousand devices quickly, preferably within a minute. I know that there is no certainty that the message will ever be delivered and that Google may delay the message due to different circumstances.

My implementation for iOS is about the same except of course the sending part. That takes about 5 sec for 15000 messages. For 5000 messages to Android it takes over an hour which is way to long.

Does anyone know a way to speed this up?
Or does Google stop this kind of mass push to stop spam?

The C2DM part of the code is below. This is in PHP but I have no problem reading most other programming languages.
I use a script to connect() once and then loop all tokens and use sendMessage() to send each message. After all messages is sent, it disconnect().

```
<?php
class C2DMclient
{
    private $authKey = NULL;
    private $ch = NULL;

    function connect() {
        $post_params = array(
            'Email'       => 'C2DM_USER',
            'Passwd'      => 'C2DM_PWD',
            'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
            'source'      => 'appname',
            'service'     => 'ac2dm',
        );
        $first = true;
        $data_msg = '';

        foreach($post_params as $key => $value) {
            if($first)
                $first = false;
            else
                $data_msg .= '&';

            $data_msg .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
        }

        $x = curl_init('C2DM_CLIENTLOGIN');
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_msg);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($x);
        curl_close($x);

        $pos = strpos($response, 'Auth=');
        $this->authKey = trim(substr($response, 5 + $pos));
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'C2DM_SERVER');
    }

    function disconnect() {
        curl_close($this->ch);
        $this->authKey = NULL;
    }

    function sendMessage($deviceToken, $message) {
        $data = array(
            'registration_id' => $deviceToken,
            'collapse_key'    => 'ck_type',
            'data.type'       => 'TYPE',
            'data.message'    => $message,
            'data.title'      => 'Title'
        );
        $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$this->authKey);

        if($headers)
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        $messagedata = curl_exec($this->ch);
            return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
New solution is based on curl_multi_exec.

Curl handles are collected while looping through the database query results. After a few hundred curl handles are gathered, sendMessages($chs) are called to send all those messages. At the moment I collect 700 messages before sending and seems to have a good delivery rate and fast enough, ~10s to send 5000 messages. A higher number seem to affect delivery rate.

```
<?php
class C2DMclient
{
    private $authKey = NULL;
    private $ch = NULL;

    function connect() {
        $post_params = array(
            'Email'       => 'C2DM_USER',
            'Passwd'      => 'C2DM_PWD',
            'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
            'source'      => 'appname',
            'service'     => 'ac2dm',
        );
        $first = true;
        $data_msg = '';

        foreach($post_params as $key => $value) {
            if($first)
                $first = false;
            else
                $data_msg .= '&';

            $data_msg .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
        }

        $x = curl_init('C2DM_CLIENTLOGIN');
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_msg);
        curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($x);
        curl_close($x);

        $pos = strpos($response, 'Auth=');
        $this->authKey = trim(substr($response, 5 + $pos));
    }

    function getMessageCurlHandle($deviceToken, $message) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'C2DM_SERVER');
        $data = array(
            'registration_id' => $deviceToken,
            'collapse_key'    => 'ck_type',
            'data.type'       => 'TYPE',
            'data.message'    => $message,
            'data.title'      => 'Title'
        );
        $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$this->authKey);

        if($headers)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        return $ch;
    }

    function sendMessages($chs) {
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        foreach($chs as $ch) {
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        }
        $active = null;
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        while($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            if(curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                } while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Update]** C2DM is now [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/). It's successor [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) supports [multiple receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#send-msg) aka batch sending:

```
{ "data": {
  "score": "5x1",
  "time": "15:10"
  },
  "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

**[/Update]**

C2DM [doesn't support](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/ddb6290d068cdc23/7d7104083d02d73d) batch sending yet.

However you could send several POST request to the C2DM server at the same time,
unfortunately PHP has itself no support for multi-threading.

Have a look at [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) which gives the possiblity to make several cURL requests at the same time.

Comment: I know that C2DM doesn't support batch sending and therefor I make one POST for each message. For some reason this process takes a really long time. I will take a look at curl_multi_exec. Maybe it's curl itself that take to much time. I will time a bit more and return if I find something interesting.

Comment: curl_multi_exec seemed to be the solution. After testing it for a few days the time to send 5000 messages went from over an hour to a matter of seconds. However it's quite random if the message is ever receive the messages. Some seem to get lost on the way. I guess 2000 messages at once is to many and I will try to tweak this for optimal performance vs speed. I will update the original post when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

Also I would investigate Firebase, I've been playing with them quite a bit lately, and it seems really quick. They have API's for a pretty wide range of frameworks. Their goal is to push changes to datasets (messages are a perfect example) very quickly, so when a change happens they send a notification message out to all connected users.

https://www.firebase.com/